# Make something happen when app opens from background?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I want to run a function when my application opens from the background (after someone has pressed home button and reopened the app).
I have been told to look into "NSNotificationcenter" and "applicationdidbecomeactive", but I have no idea how to use those. And yes I have been searching online.. Can anyone please help me with this one?

Comment: Open XCode. Select the help menu. Select search, and search in the Xcode help system. It documents the applicaitonDidBecomeActive notification. Don't just Google search - read Apple's docs. They are quite comprehensive, and should be the first place you look.

Comment: And it will help if you provide more details about what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Appdelegate class there are methods which invoke on app becoming active and going to background.Do code in them to do things which you want to do when the app goes to background or becomes active.